# What is wrong with my code? c++

Tags: c++, primes

I'm trying to output all prime numbers up to the number entered and I can't figure out why it's not working.

Could someone take the time to explain what I did wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int number;

    cout << "Enter Number: ";
    cin >> number;

    for (int a = 2;a <= number;a++)
    {

        bool prime = false;

        for (int b = 2;b < a;b++)
        {
            if (a%b == 0)
            {
                prime = true;
                break;
            }

            if (prime = true)
                cout << a << endl;
        }       
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A couple of obvious points: 1) a prime number is one that is *not* divisible by any number except 1 and itself, 2) `=` is assignment. When you want to do comparison, you want `==` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
if (a%b == 0)
{
    prime = true;
        break;
}
```

You must write it like this:

```
if (a%b == 0)
{
    prime = false;
        break;
}
```

Also Change `bool prime = false;` to `bool prime = true;`

Finaly this code:

```
if (prime == true)
    cout << a << endl;
```

Must be outside the `for loop`

Your code will be better like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number;

    cout << "Enter Number: ";
    cin >> number;

    for (int a = 2; a <= number; a++)
    {

        bool prime = true;

        for (int b = 2; b < a; b++)
        {
            if (a%b == 0)
            {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (prime == true)
            cout << a << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Result (example):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(i=2;i<=number;i++)
 {
         ct=0;
         for(j=2;j<i;j++)
         {
             if(i%j==0)
                 {
                       ct=1;
                       break;
                 }
         }
         if(ct==0)
         {
             printf("%d \t",i);
         }
 }
```